# How to add sales/guest/form to cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, forms

I'd like to add the sales guest form to a cms page?  This is the form you find at yourdomain.com//sales/guest/form/ it's template is `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/guest/form.phtml`

[image: Sales Guest form]

I've tried using this method which outlines how to do it for the Magento contacts form but am not sure how to re-work this method for the sales/guest/form, I think my `action` attribute is wrong.

This is what I have

```
<!– Order Search Form –>
{{block type="core/template" name="orderSearchForm" form_action="/sales/guest/view" template="sales/guest/form.phtml"}}
<!– Order Search Form –>
```

This displays the form on the page but when I submit it, it just reloads the page rather than find the order at ourdomain.com/sales/guest/view/

Comment: This doesn't look like native functionality. At least I can't find the file you're talking about. Is this a module?

Comment: @SanderMangel, it is native functionality, at least in 1.9, if you go to yourdomain.com//sales/guest/form/ you will see the form.  The template is app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/guest/form.phtml

Comment: why was this question voted to be closed?  If you are going to vote to close the question, at least give some feedback!

Comment: Was me, sawry, wasn't looking correctly. Answering right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `layout/sales.xml` layout file the block is included as follows

```
<block type="sales/widget_guest_form" name="guest.form" template="sales/guest/form.phtml"/>
```

In the phtml file `sales/guest/form.phtml` the method `getActionUrl` retrieves the post action URL. This method returns a standard value that can't be set from layout XML

```
 /**
     * Return quick search form action url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActionUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('sales/guest/view', array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure()));
    }
```

Including the block like this would solve it I'd say

```
{{block type="sales/widget_guest_form" name="orderSearchForm" template="sales/guest/form.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to offer an alternative:

The above answers work fine, however you could add the following in the the **Layout > Layout update XML** section of your CMS page:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block after="-" type="sales/widget_guest_form" name="guest.form" template="sales/guest/form.phtml"/>
    <action method="insert" ifconfig="sales/widget_guest_form">
        <block>guest.form</block>
    </action>
</reference>
```

This way, clients are also less likely to edit this tab since it's not within the content section!

Hope this helps anyone else with this issue!

Comment: great solution.